# Curl class in codeIgniter 3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I'm a beginner in Codeigniter.I use CI 3.0 (last version).I wanna use recaptch in my code.When I search in google for curl class in codeigniter I find this code

```
$this->load->library('curl');
```

but when I use this in my code

> Unable to load the requested class: Curl

and reality there isn't this class. 
Can anybody help me pleas?
Thanks.

Comment: check curl is install or not ???

Comment: @Saty there isn't any class with Curl name in library.

Comment: check `<?php

phpinfo();


?>` curl in install or not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `curl` library is not contained in the default library - you will need to install the [curl extension](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl) for code-igniter.

But: please consider that this library is marked as deprecated.
You should try using another library like [guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) etc.